# What other operating systems besides Unix is POSIX compatible with?

Tags: unix, posix

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX

> POSIX (/ˈpɒzɪks/ POZ-iks), an acronym for Portable Operating System Interface,[1] is a family of standards specified by the IEEE Computer Society for maintaining compatibility between operating systems. POSIX defines the application programming interface (API), along with command line shells and utility interfaces, for software compatibility with variants of Unix ***and other operating systems***.

The problem is that they say clearly "variants of Unix" and "other operating systems".

***By "other operating systems", which operating systems are they referring to?***

Comment: My guess would be Linux.

Comment: @melpomene Isn't that a Unix variant?

Comment: Linux is _not_ a Unix variant! Linux behaves similar to Unix in many aspects. It shares the same principles. But its internal setup is _completely_ different and it has implemented areas that simply do not exist in Unix.

Comment: I think that even MS-Windows passes the Posix requirements these days. but I am not familiar with that system, I only saw that mentioned myself.

Comment: Actually, the Wikipedia article holds a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX

Comment: In spirit, yes, but it doesn't use any of the original Unix code (neither [SysV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V) nor [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution)). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system#Unix_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) says "Four operating systems are certified by The Open Group (holder of the Unix trademark) as Unix." But maybe I'm wrong and they're referring to Windows? Apparently WinNT was [technically compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_POSIX_subsystem) with POSIX.1.

Comment: @melpomene this page shows Linux as a Unix variant: http://computer.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Unix_variants

Comment: @melpomene, it is well known Linux is not POSIX: asserting POSIX compliance requires a POSIX certification (for the last major version of the environment at least), and no one is willing to pay for it, since in Linux culture, payment is a big no‑no. Also note GNU is No Unix may more means what it means than you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, POSIX is a set of standards so depending on which one you are talking about, you'll find more or less compatible OSes.

Second, any OS complying with the POSIX set of interfaces might be allowed to name itself UNIX so strictly speaking, there can be no POSIX compatible non Unix OS.

The ambiguity comes to the fact Unix is used to name two different things. The first one is the family of OSes having their roots in the original AT&T Unix source code. The second acceptation is any OS which share the same set of interfaces defined by POSIX. Gnu/Linux OSes belong to the latter group.

Anyway, there are only two POSIX compliant OSes (i.e. certified to be compliant) not belonging to the Unix family, QNX and OS X (although the latter shares some code with BSD which has its root in the original Unix).

There are much more compatible still not strictly compliant OSes around. Cygwin, SFU and similar layers are providing a subset of POSIX compatible APIs to Windows. Other non Unix like ones are VxWorks, z/OS, OpenVMS.

For a complete list, have a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX-oriented_operating_systems

Comment: so, basically by "other operating systems" they are not referring to Windows by any means?

Comment: They are not referring to Windows specifically but Windows used to provide a POSIX compliant subsystem until Windows 2003 but it was essentially useless and unused. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_POSIX_subsystem for details. Nowadays, Cygwin and SFU are the most common ways to provide some Unix compatibility to Windows.